# Cannot get pi from a c library called from python using ctypes

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I want to discover how to use the python's built-in ctypes module. I wrote a simple c/c++ code which returns pi's multiples:

```
#define pi 3.14159265358979323846 //I tried this one too, not works.
double ppi(int n){
return n*3.14159265358979323846; //The same number multiplied by n
}
```

I compiled it with the MinGW came with the Code::Blocks using the command

```
 gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,mylib.so -o mylib.so -fPIC mylib.c
```

I got a cute .so file & I tried to use it in a python code:

```
 from ctypes import CDLL
 myModule=CDLL('mylib.so')
 print(myModule.ppi(1))
 print(myModule.ppi(2))
```

But it returns:

```
 2226964
 2226964
```

Any idea why it happens?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Return Types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types) documentation:

> By default functions are assumed to return the C `int` type. Other return types can be specified by setting the `restype` attribute of the function object.

So you should do:

```
myModule.ppi.restype = c_double
print(myModule.ppi(1))
print(myModule.ppi(2))
```

Comment: Thank you so mutch! It fixed this error, now I can use it in my code.